# Mocking a model class inherit from SDK Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am getting start with writing unit test for all my models classes in my project.

There is a class method in `QUUserModel` I would like to test in this case:

```
+ (BOOL)isRegistedPhoneNumber:(NSString *) phoneNumber{
    AVQuery *query = [AVUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"mobilePhoneNumber" equalTo:phoneNumber];
    return [query countObjects] > 0;
}
```

So what I achieved is just look likes:

```
#import <Specta.h>
#define EXP_SHORTHAND
#import <OCMock.h>
#import "QUUserModel.h"
#import <Expecta.h>

SpecBegin(QUUserModel)

describe(@"QUUserModel", ^{
    it(@"is registered with phone number", ^{
        id userModel = OCMClassMock([QUUserModel class]);
                                                 ~~~~~
    });
});

SpecEnd
```

This raised an error:

> No known class method for selector 'class'

I noticed that the `QUUserModel` class is subclassing of `AVUser`, a class from SDK.

```
@interface QUUserModel : AVUser<AVSubclassing>
```

Any one could guide me to what I can do ?